# In LaTeX, how to generate PDF with only sections (not sub or subsubsections)

Tags: latex

Is there a package or flag to pdflatex or xelatex such that if I have a document structured like

```
\begin{document}

\maketitle

\section{S1}
General stuff 1

\subsection{details}
kewrweklrweewrwerwe

\section{S2}
General stuff 2

\subsection{d2}
Lorem ipsum
\subsubsection{d3}
Even more details
\end{document}
```

How can I quickly generate a pdf that has just section1 general stuff 1 and section 2 general stuff 2, but no subsections?

Thanks!

Comment: Hi, there's now a dedicated SO derivative for TeX questions. Please ask it again at tex.stackexchange.com.

Comment: AFAIK there is no such thing, because LaTeX does not have a concept of the content of a section or a subsection - These are just titles and TOC entries.  You can hack your way pretty easily with sed, though, assuming that the content in the sections does not refer to subsections.

Answer (score 1):

Here is an extremely hackish attempt that is very fragile. Use only for testing purposes.

```
\documentclass{article}

\newbox\trashbox

\let\normalsection\section
\let\normalsubsection\subsection
\let\normalenddocument\enddocument
\protected\def\subsection{%
  \protected\def\section{%
    \egroup
    \let\section\normalsection
    \normalsection
  }%
  \protected\def\enddocument{%
    \egroup
    \let\enddocument\normalenddocument
    \normalenddocument
  }%
  \setbox\trashbox=\vbox\bgroup
  \normalsubsection
}

\title{abc}

\begin{document}

\maketitle

\section{S1}
General stuff 1

\subsection{details}
kewrweklrweewrwerwe

\section{S2}
General stuff 2

\subsection{d2}
Lorem ipsum
\subsubsection{d3}
Even more details
\end{document}
```